# Create an AdapterFactory for gson for dynamic Types

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

I have a JSON string that I need to converted to data class object in Kotlin, the problem is that there is a field (details) that can have a different structure depending of the value of another field like this

```
val jsonString1 = "{'name': 'Juan', 'phase': 'step1', 'details': { 'name': 'product 1' }}"

val jsonString2 = "{'name': 'Juan', 'phase': 'step2', 'details': { 'position': 10 }}"
```

now I have something like

```
data class Customer(
  var name: String? = null
  var phase: String? = null
  var details: Details? = null
)

data class Details(
  var name: String? = null
)

data class Details2(
  var position: Int? = null
)
```

now with gson I know I can

```
Gson().fromJson(jsonString1, Customer::class.java)
```

I want to be able to automatically use the right data class depending on the value of the phase field, I know I can create an adapterFactory, but I can't figure out how, an in kotlin is worse

I was reading this post
http://anakinfoxe.com/blog/2016/02/01/gson-typeadapter-and-typeadapterfactory/
and I'm pretty sure is the way to go, but I can't quite get it

Comment: You need generic class like : `Gson().fromJson(jsonString1, T::class.java)`

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48870362/6413377) (Java based) if it is to be of any help.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it's pretty easy to write such adapter. I've slightly changed your example:

```
data class Customer(
    var name: String? = null,
    var phase: String? = null,
    var details: Details? = null
)

sealed class Details {
    data class Details1(var name: String? = null) : Details()
    data class Details2(var position: Int? = null) : Details()
}

class CustomerDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Customer> {
    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type?, context: JsonDeserializationContext?): Customer {
        val customerObject = json.asJsonObject
        val detailsObject = customerObject.getAsJsonObject("details")
        val details = if (detailsObject.has("name")) {
            Details.Details1(detailsObject.get("name").asString)
        } else {
            Details.Details2(detailsObject.get("position").asInt)
        }
        return Customer(
            name = customerObject.get("name").asString,
            phase = customerObject.get("phase").asString,
            details = details
        )
    }
}

fun main() {
    val gson = GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Customer::class.java, CustomerDeserializer())
        .create()
    println(gson.fromJson(jsonString1, Customer::class.java))
    println(gson.fromJson(jsonString2, Customer::class.java))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data class Customer(
  var name: String? = null
  var phase: String? = null
  var details: Details? = null
)

data class Details(
  var name: String? = null
  var position: Int? = null
)
```

Define Details class in this way

```
Gson().fromJson(jsonString1, Customer::class.java)
```

return a Customer either name is null or position is null

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I will like to avoid this cause is not as elegant as I wanted